# programs can't use symlink folders

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive, vlc, symbolic-link

I have few symlink folders to my HDD hard drive (I have Hybrid hard drive and my home folder is on my SSD hard drive), and apps such as vlc media player and spotify can't open,use that folder, for example(my videos folder is symlink):
 `VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///home/parsa/Videos/video.mp4'. Check the log for details.`

or spotify crashes when I want to import local songs from those folders.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the snap of VLC, that's probably why. The snap uses the `home` interface to access files in your home folder. It may also use the `removable-media` interface (see `snap connections vlc`) to read data on removable devices like USB keys and mounted volumes.

So what's happening is the sandboxing security features of snap is blocking this. The workaround is to use "bind mounts" instead of symlinks. So you could for example `sudo mount -o bind /meda/bigdisk /home/Videos/bigdisk` and VLC should be able to see that.

Comment: Thank you! Anyone trying to do symlinks with their home dir, to use a syncing tool like DropBox, this will solve the snap issue.